# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+20AC from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

In console:

```
"DÃ©veloppement".encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")

str= "capital buffers for ccps â€˜the way forwardâ€™, says cpmi chair"

str.encoding.name #"UTF-8"

str.encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
```

> #Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+20AC from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

I want to convert `str` to Readable String.

Comment: Try `cp1252` instead of `iso-8859-1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.